# Accessing GUI from another class via a static helper class

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I just wanted to ask if the following code is a valid method to access the GUI from another class, or if it is bad practice. What I want to do is to write log messages into a RichTextBox in Form1.

If it's bad practice, would it be better to pass a reference of my Form1 to the other class to be able to access the RichTextBox.

I have the following code to access the GUI in my Form1 from another class:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();             
        Logger.Init(this.rtbLog);

        MyOtherClass myOtherClass = new MyOtherClass();
        myOtherClass.DoSomething();
    } 
}

public class MyOtherClass
{
    public void DoSomething()
    {
        Logger.AppendText("text...");
        Logger.AppendText("text...");
        Logger.AppendText("text...");
    }
}

public static class Logger
{
    private static RichTextBox _rtb;

    public static void Init(RichTextBox rtb)
    {
        _rtb = rtb;
    }

    public static void AppendText(String text)
    {
        _rtb.AppendText(text);
        _rtb.AppendText(Environment.NewLine);
    }
}
```

With Events (thanks to Ondrej):

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();             

        Logger.EntryWritten += Logger_EntryWritten;

        MyOtherClass myOtherClass = new MyOtherClass();
        myOtherClass.DoSomething();
    }

    void Logger_EntryWritten(object sender, LogEntryEventArgs args)
    {           
        rtbLog.AppendText(args.Message);
        rtbLog.AppendText(Environment.NewLine);
    }
}

public class MyOtherClass
{
    public void DoSomething()
    {
        Logger.AppendText("text...");
        Logger.AppendText("text...");
        Logger.AppendText("text...");
    }
}

public static class Logger
{
    public static event EventHandler<LogEntryEventArgs> EntryWritten;

    public static void AppendText(string text)
    {
        var tmp = EntryWritten;
        if (tmp != null)
            tmp(null, new LogEntryEventArgs(text));
    }
}

public class LogEntryEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    private readonly String message;

    public LogEntryEventArgs(String pMessage)
    {
        message = pMessage;
    }

    public String Message
    {
        get { return message; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, you probably want to separate it even further. This will not work for cross-thread calls, for example. In any case, you don't really want much of public static stuff anyway - having it for a logger isn't too bad, but you will eventually find yourself knee-deep in spaghetti code that's very hard to partition or think about. Passing it as a parameter will make it more reasonable. Making the logged information part of the output of the methods you call also might, depending on your use case.

Comment: Revers it and pass the pass the UI (or an interface that the UI implements) into the logger. Don't pass the actual UI controls to your logger because you dont want to fill your logger logic with UI specific logic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's probably fine for a small throw-away project, but otherwise a logger should not know anything about used platform. Then it would be good to use events for example. Raise an event whenever there's a new log entry written and consumers interested in logged entries will subscribe to a delegate.

Also be careful with threads. If you log a message from a different thread than UI you will end up with an exception because you would access a GUI control from a different thread which is forbidden.

**EDIT:**

Something along these lines. `LogEntryEventArgs` is a type you have to create and you can give it properties like `Message`, `TimeWritten`, `Severity`, etc.

```
public static class Logger
{
    public static event EventHandler<LogEntryEventArgs> EntryWritten;

    public static void AppendText(string text)
    {
        var tmp = EntryWritten;
        if (tmp != null)
            tmp(null, new LogEntryEventArgs(text));
    }
}

consumer:

Logger.EntryWritten += Logger_OnEntryWritten;

void Logger_OnEntryWritten(object sender, LogEntryEventArgs args)
{
    _rtb.AppendText(args.Message);
    _rtb.AppendText(Environment.NewLine);
}
```

Also, don't forget to invoke on a form/dispatch the body of `Logger_OnEntryWritten` in order to avoid cross-thread access exception (in case you are considering using threads).

Comment: Thanks! Do you have a link on how to solve such a scenario using events?